# AWS S3 - Java SDK - Retrieve tags for batch of keys

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I did not find any way to retrieve tag information for a batch of keys, I only found this "one key" tag request in AWS documentation :

```
GetObjectTaggingRequest getTaggingRequest = new GetObjectTaggingRequest(bucketName, keyName);
GetObjectTaggingResult getTagsResult = s3Client.getObjectTagging(getTaggingRequest);
```

The thing is that I want to retrieve hundreds of thousands of files with their associated tag values, and the way it's documented above will lead to one API request for each key, which is super slow ( way too slow).

The way I retrieve the different keys in S3 is by default batched as follows :

```
ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucketName);
...
result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(req);
```

Is there any way to retrieve tag information in the same batch fashion ?

Comment: You may want to consider building a separate index (e.g. in DynamoDB, Elasticsearch, or MariaDB) allowing you to make this query efficiently. It could be maintained via Lambda on S3 event triggers.

Comment: This job itself is meant to be run in a lambda.. if we have to maintain an index, this will get more and more complex :/ So strange AWS does not provide tag information in the objectSummary..